# Remove default CAB items in TextView selection ActionMode

Tags: android, textview, android-actionmode

I'm trying to remove default items, such as "Copy" and "Select All", from the CAB when the user selects some text from a **TextView** element.

I've overridden the default action using this code, but inflating a new menu resource doesn't remove default items.

```
textView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

        mode.setTitle("Test");
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_menu_selection, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

    }
});
```

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: try to return false in onCreateActionMode()

Comment: returning false doesn't show the arrows which let the user extends his selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the default items you can call `menu.clear()` before inflate the new menu:

```
textView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

        menu.clear();

        mode.setTitle("Test");
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_menu_selection, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize it was that simple