# Android Remove CAB menu from textView Custom Selection Action Mode

Tags: android, textview

I added a custom context menu via this code.

The ns_text_menu.xml contains only two items.

```
this.textViewTest.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

                menu.clear();

                mode.setTitle("Menu");
                mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ns_text_menu, menu);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

                if (item.getTitle().equals("View Vocab")) {

                    ErrorController.showToast(mContext, "View Vocab : " + textViewTest.getText().toString().substring(textViewTest.getSelectionStart(), textViewTest.getSelectionEnd()));

                }else{//cpy
                    ErrorController.showToast(mContext, "Copy : " + textViewTest.getSelectionStart() + ", " + textViewTest.getSelectionEnd());

                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

            }
        });
```

As mentioned in this answer([Remove default CAB items in TextView selection ActionMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33597729/remove-default-cab-items-in-textview-selection-actionmode)), I used the code

```
menu.clear();
```

on the onCreateActionMode to clear default CAB menus. It cleared some of the default context menus, but still, these two menu remains:

'select all' and 'dictionary'.

The test machine is galaxy s9+(android 8.0), and a nexus emulator(6.0).

They both show unexpected menus.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the unexpected menus are added on onPrepareActionMode.

To resolve this,

(1) store my custom menu's ids on a global list. 
(2) in onPrepareActionMode, remove every menu that does not match the ids stored on the above list.

The code looks like this.

```
this.textViewTest.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

            private List<Integer> validResIdList = new ArrayList<>();

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {


                menu.clear();
                validResIdList.clear();

                mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ns_text_menu, menu);

                for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {

                    validResIdList.add(menu.getItem(i).getItemId());
                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {


                List<Integer> toRemoveResId = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {

                    if (menu.getItem(i).getItemId() != (validResIdList.get(0)) && menu.getItem(i).getItemId() != (validResIdList.get(1))) {

                        toRemoveResId.add(menu.getItem(i).getItemId());
                    }
                }

                for (Integer resId : toRemoveResId) {
                    menu.removeItem(resId);
                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

                if(validResIdList != null && validResIdList.size() > 0){

                    if (item.getItemId() == validResIdList.get(0)) {

                        ErrorController.showToast(mContext, "View Vocab : " + textViewTest.getText().toString().substring(textViewTest.getSelectionStart(), textViewTest.getSelectionEnd()));
                        mode.finish();

                    } else {//cpy
                        ErrorController.showToast(mContext, "Copy : " + textViewTest.getSelectionStart() + ", " + textViewTest.getSelectionEnd());
                        mode.finish();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

            }
        });
```

The reason why I'm using validResIdList over R.id.xxx is because I'm implementing this on a library project.

If you are in an application project, you may use the R.id.xxx to figure out which menu you are dealing with.